# Wordpress 2014 Theme - Featured Content with multiple tags?

Tags: php, functions, theme-twenty-fourteen

My company is using the new 2014 Theme for our portfolio blog. We really like the Featured Content section on the home page.

What we would like to do is have multiple pages all with different Featured Content sections.

This is how much we have been able to work out so far.

All of the key information is held in `/inc/featured-content.php`.

This gets handed to `functions.php` under the class featured-content, and then onto featured-content.php (note the lack of `/inc/`) under the class `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts`, and finally, gets called on `page.php` under the class featured-content once again.

We want to target the variable tag-name with different tags on different pages. Our plan is to create a number of page templates, all with something in them forcing featured-content to call up a different tag.

While we are moderately versed with PHP, we are not sure how to code this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has worked? What hasn't? As-written, this question's scope is far too broad for WPSE.

Comment: I've looked into using arrays to call the tags, but nothing is working. I could use a bit of guidance.

Comment: "*I could use a bit of guidance*" - please **edit your question** to include any relevant code that you've already tried, and a description of what it's intended to do, and what's not working as expected.